# finding element by classname and tagname using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

There are classes and tagname and I am writing the below selenium code to find description from below code but its not working.

```
WebElement WWdescription = driver.findElement(By.className("atb-delivery-accordions").className("section highlight-01").tagName("p"));    


<div class="atb-delivery-accordions">
    <div class="page-accordion opened">
    <input id="moreDetails-acc" class="acc-check" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <label class="acc-label opened" data-panel-id="moreDetailsAcc" for="moreDetails-acc">Description</label>
    <div class="content" data-panel-id="moreDetailsAcc" style="display: block;">
    <div class="information-panel">
    <div class="subcontent">
    <div class="section highlight-01">
    <p>A pretty floral lace collection combining contrast bows and trims for a feminine on trend look. The fuller coverage of our post surgery bras provide support, comfort and confidence. The dual cotton pockets are perfect for a prosthesis. Combine style and value with this pack of 2 bras.</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
 WebElement parentEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='atb-delivery-accordions']"));

 WebElement descriptionEle = parentEle.findElement(By.tagName("p"));

 //Get the text from the description element.
 String descriptionText = descriptionEle.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use XPath or CSS selector instead of other locaters i.e., className, id, name or tagName.
I also experienced the same i.e., when I tried with XPath I was able to locate the element properly and was able to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
WebElement description = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='atb-delivery-accordions']/p"));
```

String descriptionText=description.getText();